# Bootstrap Image carousel text/indicators missing on small screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have a Bootstrap carousel that is fine on a large screen, but if i reduce the screen size the indicators move below the image and I lose the headline text completely. I must be missing something. I want to have the indicators and text across the image as with a larger screen. Any help appreciated...

```
<div class="container" id="index">
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

   <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Example headline</h3>
        <p>Example description</p>
      </div>
      <img src="img/lesson8-portfolioheroimage2.jpg" alt="...">

    </div>


    <div class="item">
      <img src="img/portfolioheroimage.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Example headline</h3>
        <p>Example description</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="img/portfolioheroimage3.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Example headline</h3>
        <p>Example description</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Here is my CSS if that helps .carousel {
 margin-left: -15px;
 margin-right: -15px;
}


.carousel-inner{
 height: 400px;
}
.carousel-caption {
 padding-bottom: 450px;
}

.carousel-control {
 margin: 200px 0;
}

Comment: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/simple-responsive-carousel It's an example of Bootstrap responsive carousel. You have the CSS and the HTML code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because the image in the carousel getting resized according to its aspect ratio when you resize the screen size.

remove `.carousel-control { margin: 200px 0; }` and for `.carousel-caption` instead of `padding-bottom` give `bottom` in `%` and adjust it according to your requirement in `media queries`.

Also add this `css`

```
.carousel-inner .item{
    height: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner .item img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100% !important;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```css
.carousel { margin-left: -15px; margin-right: -15px; }
.carousel-inner{ height: 400px; }
.carousel-caption { bottom: 30% !important; } 
.carousel-inner .item{
    height: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner .item img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100% !important;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>

<div class="container" id="index">
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

   <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Example headline</h3>
        <p>Example description</p>
      </div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="...">

    </div>


    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Example headline</h3>
        <p>Example description</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Example headline</h3>
        <p>Example description</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! Seems to work perfectly. I'd never have got that on my own! Cheers.

Comment: Actually, can i just ask....that makes the image on a large screen fill the page, whereas I wanted the height to be less. Tried altering the CSS but nothing happens, any ideas?

Comment: Sorry I'm not clear with your question. Means you want the image to have 100% of screen width and restricted height ?

Comment: Ah sorry. So the width is as I wanted, (filling the container) but I'd like to adjust the height of the images in the carousel. Is this possible with CSS or should I just crop the image itself? I've tried to change            .carousel-inner .item img {    
    height: 100% !important;
} to a different percentage but it doesn't affect the height of the image. Thanks.

Comment: you can adjust height of images by adjusting `.carousel-inner{ height: 400px; }`

Comment: according to `.carousel-inner .item img { height: 100% !important; }` images take `100%` of its parents height i.e, `.carousel-inner`. So you can adjust `.carousel-inner` height

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the size of carousel item, You should adjust the image height in the CSS file. Changing the carousel item will show caption till 80% screen width, but smaller than that it will disappear.

```
img {
max-height: 600px;
}
```